# WPF Custom TextBox ContextMenuOpening Problem

Tags: wpf, contextmenu

I've got an issue with a custom control that I've written not firing it's ContextMenuOpening event when I hook it up programatically. The control is basically a wrapper for the standard TextBox:

```
public class MyTextBox : TextBox
{
    public MyTextBox()
    {
        this.ContextMenuOpening += new ContextMenuEventHandler(MyTextBox_ContextMenuOpening);
    }

    void MyTextBox_ContextMenuOpening(object sender, ContextMenuEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("ContextMenuOpening event fired");
    }
}
```

There's nothing suspect either about the XAML:

```
<local:MyTextBox Height="25" Width="300"/>
```

For some reason though, I can never get the event to fire. I'm trying to intercept the context menu so I can alter it (it's context sensitive) and really am trying to avoid having to hook up the event everywhere the control is used - surely this is possible?

Answer (score 3):

Turns out you need to explicity set the ContextMenu to null when creating the object:

```
public MyTextBox()
{
    this.ContextMenu = null;
    this.Initialized += (s, e) =>
        ContextMenuOpening += new ContextMenuEventHandler(MyTextBox_ContextMenuOpening);
}
```

Then it works a treat :)

Comment: I checked, and "newing up" the context menu (instantiating it instead of setting it to null) works too (and feels a bit less strange!)

Answer (score 0):

The ContextMenuOpening-Event will only be fired after you assign a new context menu to the property ContextMenu:

```
public MyTextBox()
{
    this.ContextMenu = new ContextMenu();
    this.ContextMenu.Items.Add(new MenuItem {Header = "Do stuff"});
    
    ...
}
```